# How to recognize < x % coverage in gcov in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gcov

I'm trying to define a `make` target which asserts a test coverage of `x`%, i.e. fails in case a file has < `x`% test coverage, but I don't seem to find a control of the returncode of `gcov` and I'd like to avoid parsing its output.

My `make` target currently is

```
GCOV = gcov

coverage:
    $(MAKE) CFLAGS='-g -O0 --coverage'
    $(MAKE) check
    cd src && $(GCOV) -o .libs/ *.c # there're no .gcno files in lib which means that gcov can't be run on them; gcov only seems to work in the current directory
```

I'm using `gcov` 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: The only way you are going to get the percent covered is by asking `gcov` or parsing the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gcov doesn't support this, but you can use a gcov wrapper like [gcovr](http://gcovr.com) (version 3.4 or later). If you run

```
$ gcovr --fail-under-line 80
```

and have less than 80% line coverage in your project, then the gcovr command will exit with nonzero status (see the [documentation](https://gcovr.com/guide.html#cmdoption-gcovr-fail-under-line) for details). There's an analogous `--fail-under-branch` option to require a minimum branch coverage. You can use a `--filter` regex to select only those files that you are interested in.

Comment: No, please don't delete! This answer seems to have been a useful signpost for many people – I found it by looking at the gcovr referrers :) And thank you for your PRs, even if they weren't merged – they suggested a useful direction!